# Can a chrome extension take a screenshot of its own popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible for a chrome extension to take a screenshot of the visible area of its own popup window? I'd like to have a button in the popup that, when clicked, takes a picture of the popup itself so that users may use those images as supporting evidence for any support request.

Essentially I want something like `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`, but where I can target the popup window itself. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably not. Possible workarounds: a) chrome.desktopCapture and cropping, b) writing a separate utility and running it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).